# Filter location updates when using LocationManager requestLocationUpdates method

Tags: java, android, gps, locationmanager

I am an `iOS` developer learning `Android`, so please bear with me. On `iOS` when getting location updates we have to be sure to filter those and throw out invalid locations. We check for things like outdated locations based on timestamp, inaccurate locations, etc.

Is there a preferred way to do this on `Android` or is this even needed? So far I am just checking that the `location` I got is not nil:

```
// All my other code to start my LocationManager
...

@Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
 {
    if (location != null)
    {

        // Do stuff here

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not needed. However, I also encourage you to look at the new Location Services APIs offered in Google Play Services (http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html)